# jcarousel stopping the loop after one show

Tags: jcarousel, infinite-loop

I have jcarousel and I want to stop the loop after the slideshow, I have rummaged through the jquery.jcarousel.js and cannot find the function to stop it after 1 loop. Anyone have any idea where the function is?